# Rails: Having a helper in application helper, want to overwrite it in other helper and call super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have the following method in my `ApplicationController`:

```
helper_method :body_css_classes
def body_css_classes
  [controller_name, action_name]
end
```

I have it in the controller, because I want to be able to overwrite it in other controllers like this:

```
def body_css_classes
  super << @view
end
```

This works, but somehow it feels like this should be in the `ApplicationHelper`, not in the `ApplicationController`. Is there a way to move it to the helpers? As far as I can see, `super` won't be available there.

Comment: Inside the `ApplicationController`, write `helper :application`, and move the method `body_css_classes` to the `ApplicationHelper`.

Comment: Quote from my question above: "As far as I can see, super won't be available there."